# Add margin between items in a bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap grid that has 3 rows with the following layout.

[image]

All I'm trying to do is add a bit of margin between them but as you can see, the columns and rows are not longer properly aligned.

Is there a way to fix it or maybe there's a better way to achieve what I want?

```css
#featured {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.featured-1 {
  height: 200px;
}

.featured-2 {
  height: 50%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.featured-3 {
  height: 50%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row featured-1" id="featured">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 bg-warning">
      Featured 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="row featured-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-danger">
          Featured 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row featured-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-success">
          Featured 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary">For reference</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already padding on the columns, which acts as gutters. I'd put the background on your column *content* instead.

```css
#featured {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.featured-1>div {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="featured">
    <div class="col-7 featured-1">
      <div class="bg-warning">Featured 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-5 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="featured-2 flex-grow-1 bg-danger mb-1">Featured 2</div>

      <div class="featured-3 flex-grow-1 bg-success mt-1">Featured 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="bg-primary">For reference</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The official bootstrap document recommended the use of [`Gutter`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/#how-they-work).

you can do this like below:

```css
.featured-1 {
  height: 200px;
}
.featured-2, .featured-3 {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row featured-1" id="featured">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 bg-warning">
      Featured 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 px-4">
      <div class="row featured-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-danger">
          Featured 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row featured-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-success gy-2">
          Featured 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary gy-2">For reference</div>
  </div>
</div>
```